# Get Postgresql Procedure signature details using Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.5

I am looking for a way using which I can get the details like Input Parameters, Which Parameter is Input or Output Type, Data Type etc. of any stored procedure or Function created in PostgreSQL using JAVA.

Comment: `DatabaseMetadata.getProcedureColumns()`

Comment: Could you please post your code snippet that you've tried so far.